# Obtaining individual slopes from an lme4 object in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, lme4, mixed-models

I'm new to `lme4` package in R. In my example below, I was wondering if it might be possible to obtain the `gender` slopes (i.e., differences) for each `dep` after fitting my `glmer` model?

```
dat <- data.frame(dep = rep(LETTERS[1:6],each=2), gender = rep(c("Ma","Fe"),6), 
       admit=c(512,89,353,17,120,202,138,131,53,94,22,24), 
       reject=c(313,19,207,8,205,391,279,244,138,299,351,317))

lme4::glmer(cbind(admit,reject) ~ gender+dep + (gender|dep), data=dat, family=binomial)
```

Comment: For fixed effects with individual slopes you may want to look into the [`feisr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/feisr/index.html) package.

Answer (score 0):

In lme4 you can get the estimated slopes from `ranef`, but in your model you will need to sum the global and unit specific terms, as in the example below.

```
library(lme4)

dat <- data.frame(dep = rep(LETTERS[1:6],each=2), gender = rep(c("Ma","Fe"),6), 
                  admit=c(512,89,353,17,120,202,138,131,53,94,22,24), 
                  reject=c(313,19,207,8,205,391,279,244,138,299,351,317))

mod1 <- glmer(cbind(admit,reject) ~ gender+dep + (gender|dep), data=dat, family=binomial)
summary(mod1)

ran_gender <- ranef(mod1)$dep

fe_mod1 <- fixef(mod1)

slopes <- fe_mod1[[2]] + ran_gender[,2]
slopes
```